# Not allowed to use property observer

Tags: swift, properties, sprite-kit

I want two `SKSpriteNode`s to be at the same position and static to each other. I first tried setting this up in the `update()` function.

```
sprite1.position = sprite2.position
```

It gives `sprite1` the position of `sprite2` one frame before. With high speeds (changes in `sprite2`'s position ) it gets clear they are not static to each other.
I then tried using a property observer:

```
sprite2.position = sprite2Position{ didSet{ sprite1.position = sprite2.position } }
```

I'm not allowed to do this. Xcode says I have to `separate multiple statements on line`.

Comment: Why not just set `sprite1.position = sprite2.position` in the `didFinishUpdate()` method (which is called after physics and SKActions are evaluated but before the frame is drawn)

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I didn't know didFinishUpdate() existed.

Comment: If you want the sprites to be linked, why not add one as a child node of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure the sprites have the same position, set the position after physics and SKActions have been simulated. Do this in the `didFinishUpdate()` method of `SKScene`:

```
override func didFinishUpdate() {
    sprite1.position = sprite2.position
}
```